# Does python repeatedly calculate value of function appear multiple times in one formula

Tags: python

In python, if I have a function

f(x)=(g(x)+1)(g(x))

g(x) is defined before and takes time to calculate.

some thing like this

```
def g(x):
  return value
def f(x):
  return (g(x)+1)*(g(x))
```

When I am calculating f(x), will python calculate g(x) two times when substitute g(x) in to the equation? 
If it does calculate two times, how people usually handle it in python?

Comment: You can easily find this by yourself by putting a `print` call inside `g`.

Comment: Yes it will calculate it twice. You handle it by storing results in variables. This is not Python-specific, but common to all programming languages, without taking into account compiler optimizations.

Comment: You could memoize the function `g` if you want to keep it more math-like.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the function `g(x)`, yes, it will be calculated again each time it is called. A memoized function ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) will only need to calculate the value once for a given value of `x`. For example:

```
def g(x):
    if cache[x]:
        return cache[x]
    else:
        result = # calculate g(x)
        cache[x] = result
        return cache[x] # or return result
```

Comment: `calculate g(x)` should be commented.

Comment: Edited to add comments

Comment: The idea is understood but you need to compute the value in a different way (something like `cache[x] = _g(x)` where `_g` is the original function) due to infinite recursion.

Comment: Edited to avoid recursion on g(x)

Answer (score 0):

> will python calculate g(x) two times when substitute g(x) in to the
>   equation

```
  return:(g(x)+1) * (g(x))
          ^^^        ^^^
```

Yes. Since the function is called twice, it will be calculated twice.

> how people usually handle it in python

You call the function and store the value to be used later.

```
def f(x):
   value_g = g(x)
   return (value_g+1) * (value_g)
```

Comment: @dabadaba : Edited

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to check - print something in `g` and see how many times it gets printed.
Anyway, yes. It will call `g` twice.
The best way I know to handle it is to create a local variable equal to the method returned value then using it instead.

```
def f(x):
    g_result = g(x)
    return (g_result + 1) * g_result
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the first part of your question has been well answered, but as for:

> how people usually handle it in python?

If it is the case that the output from the `function` `g(x)` will be needed twice, it makes sense (at least for me) to just store it in a `variable`. Due to the nature of how a `function` should work (without `global` influences such as `time`), the same `input` should always give the same `output`.

So lets say that this `function` would take `1` minute to compute, if we wanted to use the output twice, it wouldn't make sense to ***call*** it twice as it would now take twice as long: `2` minutes. As mentioned above, you could use memoization or simply store the output of `g(x)` in a `variable`.

E.g.

```
def f(x):
   gx = g(x)
   return: (gx+1) * gx
```